# How to subtract more than 1 month in PHP variable having only month part?

Tags: php, date

I am in little trouble.

I am two variable for current month and previous month:

I only want month part

so this what I have written:

```
$current_month = date('F');
$previous_month = date('F', strtotime($current_month.' -1 F'));
```

when doing echo it prints :

`May April`

Now this works perfectly for 1 month.

But when I change the value of `-1` to something else say `-3`, it always has `May` as the value.

it prints `May - May`

I have checked it with `-3 months` but it doesn't work.

Also I have seen in docs how to subtract months from date, but they involve whole date object, I only need months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-3 month` works perfectly.

```
$current_month = date('F');
$previous_month = date('F', strtotime('-3 month'));
$previous_month = date('F', strtotime('3 month ago')); // also works
```

***[The demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2rsTTJ)***

Comment: @Abu is your date correctly set? Run `strtotime('now');` and post the output, please.

Comment: Ok I got it, I was trying to subtract from my variable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$current_month = date('F');

$previous_month = date('F', strtotime('-3 months'));

echo $previous_month;
```

This will output

```
February
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/GSfbe7)